# 'assign' and 'weak' are mutually exclusive

Tags: objective-c, ios4, twitter

I am trying TwitPic to post Image with Text over Twitter using GSTwitPicEngine class, which use YAJLiOS,

So i add YAJLiOS framework in my project and, i am getting this('assign' and 'weak' are mutually exclusive) error in the file "YAJLParser.h" that is in YAJLiOS framework.
showing Error in the following line-

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) __weak id <YAJLParserDelegate> delegate;
```

When i remove the __weak it becomes Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error.

Please help.How to handle this kinda errors.I am not getting the reason.

Comment: Shouldn't the `__weak` keyword be applied the instance variable of the class, not the getter/setter parameter types?

Answer (score 1):

silly me ...

try

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) id <YAJLParserDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: thanks for your response..but it gives error with unsafe_unretained - error - (Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error.) "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OARequestHeader", referenced from:      objc-class-ref in GSTwitPicEngine.o

Answer (score 1):

Probably you figured it out by now, 
anyways here is how I got rid of this error:

```
@property (assign) __unsafe_unretained id<YAJLParserDelegate> delegate;
```

Make sure all other declarations of `delegate` in your .h code (if any) are `__unsafe_unretained` e.g. in `@private` section:

```
__unsafe_unretained id<YAJLParserDelegate> delegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already know, **assign** and **weak** are NOT the same thing ... functionally they're very close, but weak is much more sophisticated and rather cleverly nulls out references to disposed objects to avoid crashes ( amongst other things vis retain cycles ).

Regardless - what to do? My best guess is to try pulling out ARC's backward compatibility legacy fix ... replace **_*weak*** with **_unsafe_unretained** and see how that goes.